# Why do I get "Too many indexed properties for entity" error just for 18 items in the list? (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a list property

```
tag_list = db.StringListProperty()
```

This has been working fine so far, but today when I tried to write a list with 18 items I got the `Too many indexed properties for entity:` error. I think this is a case of "exploding indexes."

This is my query:

```
query = Main.all()
query.filter("url =", url)
query.filter("owner =", user)
```

Reading the documentation my understanding is that this error will be triggered for cases where there are 2000+ items in the list. If this is triggered for 18 items, then, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? Thanks.

**Update with more code:**

```
    query = Main.all()
    query.filter("url =", url)
    query.filter("owner =", user)

    e = query.get()

    if e:
        e.tag_list = user_tag_list
        e.pitch = pitch_original
        e.title = title_ascii
        e.put()

        main_id = e.key().id()

    else:
        try:
            new_item = Main(
                url = url,
                tag_list = user_tag_list,
                pitch = pitch_original,
                owner = user,
                #title = unicode(title, "utf-8"),
                title = title_ascii,
                display = True)
            #this is where the error occurs in the logs              
            new_item.put()
```

And this is the list:

```
user_tag_list = [u'box', u'jquery', u'working', u'enter', u'initially', u'text', u'showing', u'javascript', u'overflow', u'focus', u'stack', u'field', u'impossible', u'input', u'hidden', u'element', u'toggling', u'toggled']
```

Comment: Could you show us the "list with 18 items", and the code triggers the exception? There isn't nearly enough code here to understand your problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I added the list and the line with error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of [exploding indexes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes#Python_Index_limits).

Comment: ok, I am reading that section, but my query does not have sort order as in the example there. In my case, do I need to create an index for url and owner only? Thanks

Comment: It's nothing to do with sort order, but the fact that you have more than one multiple-item property in an index.

Comment: I am confused, what is the other multiple item property in my model? I have only one list property?

Comment: In the `index.yaml` I see that there is an index `- kind: Main
  properties:
  - name: tag_list
  - name: tag_list
  - name: total_value
    direction: desc` but I no longer have "total_value" field. Can I delete this index?