# Should I remove an index with a deleted property and how? (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This is a follow up to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757230/why-do-i-get-too-many-indexed-properties-for-entity-error-just-for-18-items-in).

This is my model:

```
class Main(db.Model):
    url = db.StringProperty()
    tag_list = db.StringListProperty()
    #total_value = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)    
    pitch = db.TextProperty()
    owner = db.UserProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    display = db.BooleanProperty()
```

and this my `index.yaml`:

```
indexes:

...

- kind: Main
  properties:
  - name: display
  - name: date
    direction: desc

- kind: Main
  properties:
  - name: display
  - name: owner
  - name: date
    direction: desc

- kind: Main
  properties:
  - name: owner
  - name: date

- kind: Main
  properties:
  - name: owner
  - name: date
    direction: desc

- kind: Main
  properties:
  - name: tag_list
  - name: date
    direction: desc

- kind: Main
  properties:
  - name: tag_list
  - name: tag_list
  - name: tag_list
  - name: total_value
    direction: desc

- kind: Main
  properties:
  - name: tag_list
  - name: tag_list
  - name: total_value
    direction: desc

- kind: Main
  properties:
  - name: tag_list
  - name: total_value

- kind: Main
  properties:
  - name: tag_list
  - name: total_value
    direction: desc

...
```

I removed the property `total_value` a while back but I see that it is still indexed. What is the correct procedure to remove the indexes involving `total_value`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call appcfg with [vacuum_indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Deleting_Unused_Indexes) in order to delete indexes that are no longer defined in index.yaml.